# Maven Spring Project - Testing daos using application-context.xml in modules that don't include web

Tags: spring, testing, maven, junit

Application-context.xml is in a web module

pom
- user
- *various other modules with business logic and daos*

- web *only depends on service layer. only talk to your friends.*

Web has user as a dependency. I (shouldn't) can't make the dependency go the other way around as it would be circular so how can I test using the application context that is in web?

Do I: 
1. Duplicate the application context for the datasource info? (code smell)
2. Put DB application context in a hibernate-dependency project that is at the bottom of the dependency chain?

3. Some other answer?

Number 2 appears to be the best bet. I had the tests working when everything was in a service module but I'm trying to get more modular so I refactored the user specific service into a separate module.

Thanks for any ideas.
In reality I've chosen to add a layer between web and the modules as well called service rather than have the services in the modules layer. I don't think that's typical but it offers better information hiding and helps enforce open/closed. It's not relevant to this scenario so I have not included it.

Tools:

- Intellij 11
- Junit
- Maven 2
- Hibernate 3
- Spring 3
- MySql5.5

Comment: I left an answer with the solution I chose.

Comment: still interested in more input. Dev work I've done on this stack professionally I haven't done as much testing so I never ran into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Put the context files that do the dependency injection for the user module, inside the module itself. Remember that in spring you can have lots of context files, and you can import them.

To understand the reasoning behind this, ask yourself: Does my the web part of my application need a database or is it the backend that needs the database?

Comment: Ok.but what if there is an article module too(i should have clarified that there will be many modules that need a database.) then im guessing in refactoring speak that i want to pull up the data source and session factory as per number two in my question?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a service module between units and web to store the db context there. Web depends upon it and web level application context includes that modules context as do the tests. I'm doing service level integration testing on that layer. Unit tests will use mocked objects or hql to eliminate anything outside the unit itself.